# Uploading File via PHP shredding .xls files

Tags: php, excel, mime-types, mime

I have a chunk of code that is taking a user uploaded file, and processing it. When the user uploads a .xls file, the file is shredded. I suspect it has something to do with the MIME but I don't know too much about them. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php include ("header1.html") ?>
<!--- End --->
<tr height="100%">
    <td align="center" valign="top" style="background-image: url('images/midbg.jpg'); background-repeat:repeat-x; padding-top: 25px; " bgcolor="#e6e6e6" >

    <!--- Body begins here --->

    <table width="725"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
     <tr>
     <td width="100%" valign="top">
     <table style="margin-left:130px; margin-top:20px;">
<tr><td>
<p><strong style="font-size:12px"> </strong> </p>
<?php

$userName = $session->userName;

if ($handle = opendir('fileuploads/'.$userName)) {
    //echo "Directory handle: $handle\n";
   // echo "Files:\n";
    $path = 'fileuploads/'.$userName.'/';
    /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if(($file != "Thumbs.db") &&  ($file != ".")&&  ($file != ".."))
    {
    $attachment[] = $path.$file;
    }
}
//  echo '<p><b>Current total = '.$totalsize.'K</b></p>';
closedir($handle);
} 


    function fileName($inputfile,$userName)
{
    $separator = '/'.$userName.'/';
$output = split ($separator, $inputfile);
return $output[1];
}

$files = $attachment;
//print_r($files);
// email fields: to, from, subject, and so on
 $memberEmails = $_POST['emails'];
  $bcc = $_POST['bccAddress'];

if ($bcc != '')
{
$bcc = $memberEmails . ',' . $bcc; 
}
else
{
 $bcc = $memberEmails;
}

$to = $_POST['toAddress'];
if($to != '')
{
$to = $userName. "@place.com,". $to;
}
else
{
$to = $userName. "@place.com";
}
$cc = $_POST['ccAddress'];
$from = $userName. "@place.com"; 
$subject =$_POST['subject']; 
$message = $_POST['content'];
$message = str_replace('\"', '"',$message);
$headers = "From: ".$_SESSION['fullName']. "<$from>\n";

// boundary 
$semi_rand = md5(time()); 
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 
// headers for attachment 
if ($cc != '')
{
$headers .= "CC: ". $cc ."\n";
}

if ($bcc != '')
{
$headers .= "BCC: ". $bcc ."\n";
}
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"    {$mime_boundary}\""; 
// multipart boundary 
$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 

if( count($files) > 0)
{
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
}

// preparing attachments
for($x=0;$x<count($files);$x++){
$file = fopen($files[$x],"rb");
$data = fread($file,filesize($files[$x]));
fclose($file);
$fileName= fileName($files[$x],$userName);
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
$message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$files[$x]\"\n" . 
"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$fileName\"\n" . 
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
$y = $x +1;
if ( count($files) > $y)
{
     $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

}
}




$ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 


   if ($ok)
{
$logFile = "log/tmlog.log";
$logHandle = fopen($logFile, 'a');
$logData = "[" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "] " .$userName. " - message sent successfully (". $to. ",".$bcc .",". $cc.")\n";
fwrite($logHandle, $logData);
fclose($logHandle);
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=fileuploads/sendRm.php?msg=sent">';
}
else
{
$logFile = "log/tmlog.log";
$logHandle = fopen($logFile, 'a');
$logData = "[" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "] " .$userName. " - message failed\n";
fwrite($logHandle, $logData);
fclose($logHandle);
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=fileuploads/sendRm.php?msg=fail">';
}

}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe it's me, what do you mean by shredded?

Comment: This could is not [reproducible](http://sscce.org/) - the crucial definition of `$files` is missing. Also, I can't see either an upload or a download. You seem to be preparing an email, not receiving or sending a file upload. The Content-Type is of course wrong, it should not be but in quotes or parentheses. Also, most likely, you don't need to do any MIME handling yourself when processing uploads to your webpage. Instead, just access `$_FILES`.

Comment: @Ed. Oh, about the shredding: What shredding is taking place precisely? Can you give us links to a shredded and the original file?

Comment: @phihag - thanks...I'll update the code with some more specifics. Sorry, yes, I am preparing an email. Here's a screenshot of the byte comparison, original on left. I can't send the files for security purposes. http://i55.tinypic.com/244wako.png

Comment: Unlikely to be the problem, but please note that specs say you should be using `\r\n` instead of just `\n` to seperate headers etc. Most clients are intelligent enough to compensate, but it's best to follow the standards to the letter so there is not room for ambiguity...

Answer (score 0):

At what stage is the file damaged? At the server side immediately after the file upload, or at the email client end when the file has been emailed?

Here is the code rewritten to make it readable/standards compliant...

```
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

// headers for attachment 
if ($cc != '') $headers .= "Cc: $cc\r\n";    
if ($bcc != '') $headers .= "Bcc: $bcc\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
          . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$mime_boundary\"\r\n";

// multipart boundary 
$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n"
         . "--$mime_boundary\r\n"
         . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n"
         . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n"
         . "\r\n"
         . $message . "\r\n"
         . "--$mime_boundary";

if (count($files)) { // Add attachments
  for ($x = 0; $x < count($files); $x++){
    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($files[$x])));
    $fileName = fileName($files[$x], $userName);
    $message .= "\r\n"
              . "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n"
              . "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$fileName\"\r\n"
              . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
              . "\r\n"
              . $data . "\r\n"
              . "--$mime_boundary";
  }
}

$message .= '--';
```

Comment: Thanks. The file seems to be damaged immediately.

Comment: You mean, as soon as it arrive at the server after it was uploaded? If so, have you tried a different browser?

Comment: Sorry, misread your question. The file is damaged in the email received by users. It states that the filetype extension has been modified (though its still .xls) and then shows jibberish. I'm almost positive it has to do with MIME types but have no idea how to approach diagnosing this.

Comment: The MIME type shouldn't cause this issue, especially when you use `application/octet-stream`. Looking at the sample byte comparisons your posted, it looks like all occurences of bytes with value greater than 127 (7F) have been replaced by question marks (3F), although I would have to examine the entire comparison to confirm this. This suggests to me that the problem is cause by a binary file being interpretted as if it were 7-bit encoding (possibly the bytes are treated as signed?) somewhere along the line, and this is eating bytes that are not part of the standard 128 character ASCII table.

Comment: I think you're right. I took a more detailed look at the two comparisons and the pattern occurs through the whole set. I'm  `. "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n"` any idea if I should use something else?

Comment: I looked at that, but it shouldn't affect the attachments - it should only be applied to the `text/html` part. You could try removing it and seeing if it fixes the problem (you can get away with no value at all) but I sort of doubt it. To be perfectly honest, this is a little beyond the scope of my expertise - from the way I understand it, what you have done should work (base64 should prevent the problem). It's probably worth updating the question with this info. I have to go fix a server so I'm signing off, but if/when you find a solution I'd be interested to know what it is...

Comment: Also, are you 100% sure the file is OK after it has been uploaded? Have you tried opening the version at the server side and inspecting it?